# Entity Framework sending parameters as unicode causing performance problems

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

We have built a EF1 model over a legacy SQL Database.

In this database there are columns with non-unicode strings. These columns are also used as keys.

We had a problem with performance with one specific query. We noticed that EF was sending the parameter as Unicode.

We then rewrote this part of the code to run a SQL statement directly, and send the parameter as a non-unicode string.

The difference was as follows:

- With EF : **23000 ms**
- Without EF: **90 ms**

What appears to be happening is that SQL server takes the field from each of the 50000 rows converts it to Unicode to compare it with the parameter being sent in.

Anyone know how to get EF to send the parameter as a non-unicode string? Or any other way to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [and many other issues impacting performance] is fixed in EFv4. Your best bet is to use EFv4 (Entity Framework in .net 4.0) instead of EFv1 (Entity Framework in .net 3.5).